# Animate photo (or div) inside a frame div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

The picture is pretty much explanatory by itself. The div "behind" contains a bunch of little square photos that I want to animate smoothly. I'm really not good with jQuery animations, could anyone help me out with this?

(Window is fixed, pictures move "inside" it, animating forever since the page load)

[image]

Comment: Is this a draggable 'window' over a picture (or pictures) or is the 'window' fixed and the picture(s) move?

Comment: Window is fixed, pictures move "inside" it, animating forever since the page load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a fan of SIN/COS functions, so let me share with you my shot at this problem.

The idea is to have a function that runs forever, and as soon as possible so that the animation is smooth. I use a sin/cos functions to determine the new x (left) and y (top) coordenates of the div, and I have a series of parameters that allow the configuration of the speed and range of the animation.

Just paste this into an HTML file and test it in your browser.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="stuff" style="background: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: auto; position: relative;">
        a b c<br />
        d e f<br />
        g h i<br />
        j k l<br />
        </div>
        <script>
            var start = new Date();
            var x_speed = 0.001, // bigger ---> faster
                y_speed = 0.01, // bigger ---> faster
                x_multiplier = 300, // how far away I can go on the X axis
                y_multiplier = 20, // how far away I can go on the Y axis
                x_offset = 0,
                y_offset = 0;

            function animate() {

                var now = new Date();
                var elapsed_time = now - start;

                var x = Math.sin((elapsed_time)*x_speed) * x_multiplier + x_offset;
                var y = Math.cos((elapsed_time)*y_speed) * y_multiplier + y_offset;


                $("#stuff").css({
                    left : x,
                    top : y
                });

                setTimeout(animate, 0);
            }

            setTimeout(animate, 76);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Happy to share! If you tinker with the parameters you can make the animation run slower just like the one in your question. Just remember to have different x & y speeds so that the animation looks randomer. You could even though a little of Math.random in here to make the animation even more randomic... but you'll need to experiment for a while until it suits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

markup:

```
<div id="mask">
    <img id="pic" alt="my img" src="http://www.destination360.com/north-america/us/idaho/images/s/idaho-sawtooth-mountains.jpg">
</div>
```

css:

```
#mask{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    border:5px solid #000000;
}
#mask img{
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
}
```

js:

```
$('#pic').animate({left:-200},3000).animate({top:-50},3000); /* and so on... */
```

fiddle:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/YHAZ9/

**Edit** (looping it forever) http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/YHAZ9/4/

Comment: That's basically it. What if I want to go forever?

Comment: i.e. you could wrap that code inside a function and then with setInterval you loop it forever.. fiddleing it :)

Comment: Thanks! Already marked you as accepted. Do you know how they do that change of speed during animation? (Like, start moving fast and get slower at the end..)

Comment: You're welcome! About the speed during the animation and the type of transition easing, take a look at the doc: http://api.jquery.com/animate/
i.e. if you want to change it, set animate props this way: $('#element')animate({/*css*/},durationMS,'easing'/*, callback fn */);

Answer (score 1):

For how long? After a click?

I'm not behind my own computer right now, but try something like this:

This is for after a click:

```
$("#frame").click(
   function(){
      $("#photo").animate({"left": "-=100px"}, function(){
            $("#photo").animate({"top": "-=100px"}, function(){
                 $("#photo").animate({"left": "=100px"});
            });
      });
});
```

And so forth, after each line you can put a new line, like i did in line 3 and 4 from the code. This way the photo behind moves in a square.

Just a suggestion, don't know if this is exactly what you want.

EDIT: Btw, you can only go left, right or up and down, what might smoothen your animation is to grow the photo and shrink it. Therefore you need for instance the "width" parameter.
Check the jQuery site [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: forgot to put a time into it, but steweb helped out already I think. (the amount of milliseconds comes after the the amount of pixels).

Comment: Thanks, you both helped me.. I already have a pretty neat base to start with